# Simulate mouse presses (BUTTON 4 and 5)

Tags: mouseevent

I'm trying to create a single file in BAT (Windows Command Prompt) to simulate a Mouse Back and Mouse Forward event (which is in fact just pressing down mouse button 4 and 5). I can't find anything on the internet on how to simulate these exact events. Most of them are about clicking the left mouse button but that's not what I need.

The program should be as simple as possible as I do not want heavy coding on this one. It should be straight forward and I hope one of you could help me out. Is this even possible (with BAT)?

The reason for this is that Logitech Gaming Software wrongly executes the back and forward buttons' up event twice, which results in annoying behaviours while for example browsing a webpage and trying to go back one page. It would then go back two pages.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've been a little too quick with my question but it might help others. If you have the problem of your Logitech mouse doing double forward or backwards on browsers (Chrome, IE etc.) and in Windows Explorer please try the following.

First of all, you'll want to remove the currently mapped buttons. Be sure to select the desired profile first! So go over all three buttons (MOUSE 3, MOUSE 4 and MOUSE 5 (middle, tilt left, tilt right)) and remove their current mapping. By default (generic buttons) it will be "Middle click", "Back" and "Forward".

Now right click the profile at the top and select "Scripting". This is open a new window in which we can do some very advanced but still easy coding. Clear the whole thing and paste the code you find below in there. Press "Script" >> "Save" at the top of the window to save it and enjoy the working glory! You can easely test this by right clicking the profile again and selecting "Test profile". Now press any of the three buttons and you should get the outcome we want (down and up event only once on those exact buttons).

If you want to do some coding of your own feel free to change the script! The actual numbers to each mouse button can be found by clicking "Help" >> "Scripting API" at the top, along with some handy documentation. Keep in mind that you'll have to do this for every profile you desire. Doing this on the Default Profile seems the most reasonable for browsing.

```
    function OnEvent(event, arg)
        if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4) then
            OutputLogMessage("Pressing back button\n");
            PressAndReleaseMouseButton(4);
        elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5) then
            OutputLogMessage("Pressing forward button\n");
            PressAndReleaseMouseButton(5);
        elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 3) then
            OutputLogMessage("Pressing middle button...\n");
            PressAndReleaseMouseButton(2);
        end
        --OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %s\n", event, arg);
    end
```